Oracle SQL Query to role up to the reporting manager id based on the role level and update in the column
I am trying to create a query to get the reporting manager of each employee. but we should only consider the reporting manager for that employee if the manager role level is 13.
If the employee is reporting to manager below role level 13 let say 10 he should be rolling up to manager's reporting manager till the manager role level is 13 or greater.
This way we need to update the review Manager id beside the employee.
if employee level is already greater then or equal to 13 then his manager will be his direct reporting manager who will be greater then 13.
Below is the sample table



EMP ID
EMP Role Level
Manager ID
Review Manager ID




1
9
3



2
10
4



3
10
5



4
11
7



5
11
6



6
12
9



7
12
7



8
12
10



9
13
11



10
13
12



11
14
12



12
14
14



13
15
16



14
15
17



15
15
20



16
16
18



17
16
19



18
17
19



19
18
20



20
19





Result table should be updated like this :



EMP ID
EMP Role Level
Manager ID
Review Manager ID




1
9
3
9


2
10
4
9


3
10
5
9


4
11
7
11


5
11
6
9


6
12
9
9


7
12
7
9


8
12
10
10


9
13
11
11


10
13
12
12


11
14
12
12


12
14
14
14


13
15
16
16


14
15
17
17


15
15
20
20


16
16
18
18


17
16
19
19


18
17
19
19


19
18
20
20


20
19





if you check the above example employ 1 direct manager was 3 but Review manager id is rolled up to  manager id 9 has manager id 9 has Role Level greater then or equal to 13.
similarly done for all.
What I have tried :
I have tried search for hierarchical query which was giving me level but I am not able to make update based on the levels in the hierarchy.
I have tired updating it through java code by taking one row at a time but this process is very slow and not right.
Is there a way to update the Column "Review Manager ID" based on the reporting Manager Role Level >=13.
Ideally I am trying for a single query. if not possible I am trying for a PLSQL or java code to do this update.
Thanks

Description of the logic is a bit confusing, but if I got it right there are 2 groups of EMP_ID(s):

EMP_ID having EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13


REVIEW_MANAGER_ID is the next MANAGER_ID (as appropriate EMP_ID) having EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13 And EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= Current EMP_ROLE_LEVEL


EMP_ID having EMP_ROLE_LEVEL < 13


REVIEW_MANAGER_ID is the first MANAGER_ID (as appropriate EMP_ID) having EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13 (which is 9 in sample data provided)

If that is right then you should left join your table to itself twice - once for EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13 and once for EMP_ROLE_LEVEL < 13. Use Case expressions to select correct REVIEW_MANAGER_ID.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( EMP_ID, EMP_ROLE_LEVEL, MANAGER_ID, REVIEW_MANAGER_ID ) AS
        ( Select 1,   9,  3,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 2,  10,  4,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 3,  10,  5,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 4,  11,  7,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 5,  11,  6,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 6,  12,  9,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 7,  12,  7,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 8,  12, 10,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 9,  13, 11,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 10, 13, 12,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 11, 14, 12,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 12, 14, 14,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 13, 15, 16,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 14, 15, 17,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 15, 15, 20,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 16, 16, 18,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 17, 16, 19,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 18, 17, 19,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 19, 18, 20,   Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 20, 19, Null, Null From Dual 
        )

--    S Q L :
Select      t_0.EMP_ID, t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL, t_0.MANAGER_ID, 
            --
            Case  When t_1.EMP_ID Is Not Null 
                  Then t_1.EMP_ID 
                  When t_2.EMP_ID Is Not Null And t_2.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13 And t_0.MANAGER_ID Is Not Null
                  Then t_2.EMP_ID
            Else  Case  When t_0.MANAGER_ID Is Null Then Null
                  Else Min(Case  When t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13 Then t_0.EMP_ID End) Over()
                  End
            End   as REVIEW_MANAGER_ID
From        tbl t_0
Left  Join  tbl t_1 ON ( t_1.EMP_ID = t_0.MANAGER_ID And t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13)
Left  Join  tbl t_2 ON ( t_2.EMP_ID = t_0.MANAGER_ID And t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL < 13)
Order By    t_0.EMP_ID

/*        R e s u l t : 
    EMP_ID EMP_ROLE_LEVEL MANAGER_ID REVIEW_MANAGER_ID
---------- -------------- ---------- -----------------
         1              9          3                 9
         2             10          4                 9
         3             10          5                 9
         4             11          7                 9
         5             11          6                 9
         6             12          9                 9
         7             12          7                 9
         8             12         10                10
         9             13         11                11
        10             13         12                12
        11             14         12                12
        12             14         14                14
        13             15         16                16
        14             15         17                17
        15             15         20                20
        16             16         18                18
        17             16         19                19
        18             17         19                19
        19             18         20                20
        20             19                                   */

NOTE: The expected result from your question for EMP_ID = 4 is different - the logic as I understood it works like above giving REVIEW_MANAGE_ID 9 for EMP_ID 4 (not 11 as in your expected result)
To update the table use MERGE INTO ... USING (... above SQL ...)
MERGE INTO tbl t 
USING ( Select      t_0.EMP_ID, t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL, t_0.MANAGER_ID, 
                    --
                    Case  When t_1.EMP_ID Is Not Null 
                          Then t_1.EMP_ID 
                          When t_2.EMP_ID Is Not Null And t_2.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13 And t_0.MANAGER_ID Is Not Null
                          Then t_2.EMP_ID
                    Else  Case  When t_0.MANAGER_ID Is Null Then Null
                          Else Min(Case  When t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13 Then t_0.EMP_ID End) Over()
                          End
                    End   as REVIEW_MANAGER_ID
        From        tbl t_0
        Left  Join  tbl t_1 ON ( t_1.EMP_ID = t_0.MANAGER_ID And t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL >= 13)
        Left  Join  tbl t_2 ON ( t_2.EMP_ID = t_0.MANAGER_ID And t_0.EMP_ROLE_LEVEL < 13)
      ) x ON( x.EMP_ID = t.EMP_ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.REVIEW_MANAGER_ID = x.REVIEW_MANAGER_ID 
WHERE Nvl(t.REVIEW_MANAGER_ID, 0) != Nvl(x.REVIEW_MANAGER_ID, 0)

